# Flash + MySQL Communication

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, maps

I have a flash map application that I want to rebuild on the new flash platform (AS3).

It will pull in a load of records at the beginning of the application and then run without needing to communicate again.

Given this scenario, what would you recommend be the best (and most flexible) way to get this set of records into flash?

This is one of maps I'm working on:
http://www.norcrossga.net/map/Interface.html

It's built in Flash 7 and doesn't communicate with my MySQL Backend, I manually update the data once a month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to have a huge amount of data so XML will fit the bill nicely. Coupled with the new super sweet [e4x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML) support in as3 this will be a breeze to parse. 
You will need to use your preferred server side programming language to generate this, but there's really not getting around that.

Comment: Yup, much better than updating the data in Flash by hand every month.

Comment: Oh that's so sweet.  Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to have Flash communicating with MySQL, you'll have to use [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format). The wiki page breifly describes what it is and links to different AMF packages for a few different languages.

However, if you don't have a lot of data, it would probably be better to go with XML as grapefrukt said.